# Analogue controls

Tags: vvvvvv

Does VVVVVV support analogue control? (on PC or on console). If so, does that make it easier to play? For instance, one could stand still on a conveyor.

Comment: You've just made a great point about why VVVVVV doesn't support analogue control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VVVVVV does not support analogue control.

You move at a set speed regardless of your input method.